# How to wrap an annotation and conditionally applies it to a method

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Say I have an annotation (@RequiresAccount) introduced in another library and I'm using it in my project, is there a way to conditionally apply it to a method, e.g. apply it when the customer is from website A and not apply when customer is from website B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look and the only possibility I've found was, creating a wrapper-Annotation:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequiresAccountWrapperAspect {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  private RequiresAccountAspect requiresAccountAspect = new RequiresAccountAspect();

  @Around("@annotation(com.example.demo.components.RequiresAccountWrapper)")
  public Object checkIfRequiresAccount(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    if (requestURL.startsWith("http://localhost")) {
      requiresAccountAspect.checkAccount(joinPoint);
    }
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

So everywhere you've used your `RequiresAccount` annotation, you can use this wrapper instead. For example:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@RequiresAccountWrapper
public String h() {
  return "test";
}
```

As you can see I'm creating a new instance of the aspect. I don't know if you have access to the Aspect-class itself but if you have you can then call the method in it and pass the joinPoint. To find the URL from the request you can inject the `HttpServletRequest`.